# Sails.js socket.io in two tier application. How to define connection options?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js

Sails.js has builded socket.io support.

I'm building 2-tier application so my client works at different port than backend API (Sails).

How can I use builded socket in this scenario? How can I define connection options between my client and API for socket? Right now I just attach script tag. My client works at port 8040 and API at 1337.

```
<script src="http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
```

I'm getting error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this [documentation](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js), you can use `io.sails.url = 'https://api.mysite.com';`

Comment: Yep. I found this as well one minute before you added answer. It works well. Thanks!